# How to pass a URL as a parameter of a controller's method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a Codeigniter controller which takes a full URL as the first argument, but the passed URL inside my controller only is only showing `http:`

```
public function mydata($link)
{
   echo $link; //then it show only http: rather than the full url http://abc.com
}
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: I just used a simple example here to explain my issue but in reality i am using view to output the data so please don't say that i am outputing data inside a controller rather than view.

Comment: why are you passing a URL in the URI!? Do a post, this is not the place to put another URL, it defeats the purpose of 'clean urls'. If you really must, you would need to make the `$link` URLSafe

Comment: It would be impossible to figure out what's happening without some code...

Comment: There's no problem with that function. The problem is probably in defining the value of that variable.Show us the code which defines the variable before and when you're calling the `mydata` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Codeigniter controllers, each method argument comes from the URL separated by a `/` slash. `http://example.com`

There are a few different ways to piece together the the arguments into one string:

```
public function mydata($link)
{
    // URL: http://example.com/mysite/mydata/many/unknown/arguments

    // Ways to get the string "many/unknown/arguments"
    echo implode('/', func_get_args());
    echo ltrim($this->uri->uri_string(), '/');
}
```

#### However:

In your case, the double slash `//` may be lost using either of those methods because it will be condensed to one in the URL. In fact, I'm surprised that a URL like:

> `http://example.com/mydata/http://abc.com`

...didn't trigger Codeigniter's "The URI contains disallowed chatacters" error. I'd suggest you use query strings for this task to avoid all these problems:

> `http://example.com/mydata/?url=http://abc.com`

```
public function mydata()
{
    $link = $this->input->get('url');
    echo $link;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

if you want to pass url as parameters then use

urlencode(base64_encode($str))

ie:

```
$url=urlencode(base64_encode('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585034'));
echo $url
```

result:

```
aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy85NTg1MDM0
```

then you call:

http://example.com/mydata/aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy85NTg1MDM0

and in your controller

```
public function mydata($link)
{

$link=base64_decode(urldecode($link));
...
...
...
```

you have an encoder/decoder here:

http://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: I like these two methods in conjunction because base64 can have forward slashes in them, and urlencode can leave dots, which will cause CI to think the param is a file and cause a 404. These two methods together remove dots and forward slashes. Nice find!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issue of whether you should be passing a URL in a URL think about how you are passing it:

```
example.com/theparameter/
```

but your URL will actually look like

```
example.com/http://..../
```

See where you're going wrong yet? The CodeIgniter framework takes the parameter out of the URL, delimited by slashes. So your function is working exactly as it should.

If this is how you must do it then URL encode your parameter before passing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It worked fr me.
"encode" the value before passing

```
$value = str_replace('=', '-', str_replace('/', '_', base64_encode($album)));
```

"decode" the value after receiving

```
$value = base64_decode(str_replace('-', '=', str_replace('_', '/', $value)));
```

reference: https://forum.codeigniter.com/printthread.php?tid=40607

Answer (score 0):

I did like @user72740's until I discovered that it can still produce characters not permitted by CI like %.

What I ended up doing is converting the segment string into a hex, them back.

So I created a MY_URI that extended CI_URI and added these methods:

```
/**
* Segmentize
*
* Makes URI segments,  CI "segment proof"
* Removes dots and forwardslash leaving ONLY hex characters
* Allows to pass "anything" as a CI URI segment and coresponding function param
*
* @access   public
* @return   string
*/
public function segmentize($segment){
    if(empty($segment)){
        return '';
    }
    return bin2hex($segment);
}

/**
* Desegmentize
*
* @access   public
* @return   string
*/
public function desegmentize($segment){
    if(empty($segment)){
        return '';
    }
    return $this->hex2bin($segment);
}

/**
* hex2bin
*
* PHP 5.3 version of 5.4 native hex2bin
*
* @access   public
* @return   string
*/
public function hex2bin($hex) {
    $n = strlen($hex);
    $bin = '';
    $i = 0;

    while($i < $n){
        $a = substr($hex, $i, 2);
        $c = pack('H*', $a);
        if ($i == 0){
            $bin = $c;
        }
        else {
            $bin .= $c;
        }
        $i += 2;
    }

    return $bin;
}
```

Then used `$this->uri->segmentize($url)` to create the segment string and
`$this->uri->desegmentize($this->input->post('url', true))` to get it back into readable format.

Thus

`https://www.example.com/somewhere/over/the/rainbow`

becomes

`68747470733a2f2f7777772e6d79736974652e636f6d2f736f6d6577686572652f6f7665722f7468652f7261696e626f77`

and back.

I am sure there is a better way, like a base_convert() implementation, because this way the string can get arbitrarily long. But now I dont have to worry about = signs and padding, etc.

Comment: Intresting, can you provide and url that gives you invalid url characters? (I though urlencode handle that)...now I'm worried.